# How to select the 1 row of ID based on condition of min date (accrossing or ignoring another columns )?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to select those buyers with their first time buy and the category of their first time buy.

Here is the sample data :

```
ID   Category  Buy_date
1    Car       2019-01-01
1    Truck     2019-01-02
1    House     2019-01-03
1    House     2019-01-04

2    Car      2019-01-01
2    Car      2019-01-02
2    Truck    2019-01-03
```

My expected result:

```
ID   Category    Buy_date
1    Car         2019-01-01
2    Car         2019-01-01
```

My code:

```
select ID, category, min(buy_date) over (partition by id) from #a group by 1,2
```

Here is the result which is just incorrect:

```
ID    Category    Buy_date
1     Car         2019-01-01
1     Truck       2019-01-01
1     House       2019-01-01

2     Car         2019-01-01
2     Truck       2019-01-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

`select id, category, buy_date from test as outer_tab where buy_date = (select min(buy_date) from test where id = outer_tab.id);`

Comment: Sorry, if I add a condition that MIN of Buy_date must within January, how can I do it ?

Comment: So, if I have understood your query correctly, you want min of buy_date to be a January date otherwise it's null. Following query will first filter on the buy_date to get all the Jan dates and then apply min on them. So, you'll either get a Jan buy_date or none at all.
`select * from test as outer_tab where buy_date = (select min(buy_date) from test where id = outer_tab.id and extract(month from buy_date) = '01');`

Answer (score 2):

If you want one row per `id` , then use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (id) a.*
from a
order by id, buy_date asc;
```